# react native onPress pass view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any possibility to pass the clicked view reference on onPress?

```
<TouchableOpacity
  key={someObj.id}
  onPress={() => this.someFunction(I want to pass this view to the function)}
/>
```

Basically what I want to achieve is to add some animation when clicking the view, but since the view is in a scroll view, and I'm not able to get which element is clicked

Comment: Can you animate the View itself and play the animation wen the user pressed the button?

Comment: @Nerdragen no, because of the same issue, I don't know how to get the reference of that view.

Comment: I meant to "record" the animation within a function, and then call that function to "play" the animation.

Comment: But the problem is, the view is in a ScrollView, so there can be hundreds of them, I only want to make a specific one, which is the one user clicks, to animate.

Comment: But they'll all share the same animation. You can dispatch an event or pass in a new prop specifying the id of the view you want to play the animation.

Comment: well, haven't thought about that, is this a standard way of implementing this in react native world? I'm an iOS developer with minimum knowledge of RN. @Nerdragen

Comment: Not really a standard way, but references to views or components don't usually get passes around.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is :

```
<TouchableOpacity
  ref={(ref) => {
      this.myView = ref;
  }}
  key={someObj.id}
  onPress={() => this.someFunction(this.myView)}
/>
```

Keep in mind that there is probably a cleaner way to achieve what you want.

EDIT: If the `TouchableOpacity` is your item in a ScrollView, use a refs array. But this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, it's in a ScrollView, and there will be hundreds of TouchableOpacity, so should I add it to refs array?

Comment: You could, but you could also have a property in your data item to activate the `someFunction` on change. But we would need more code to see what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve !